# EmguCV Metadata file could not be loaded

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2017, emgucv

I just downloaded EmguCV online and I am trying to run a sample project it contains called FaceDetection. I am using Visual Studio 2017.

However I am getting this error:

> Metadata file 'C:\Emgu\emgucv-windesktop
>   3.3.0.2824\libs\Emgu.CV.UI.dll' could not be found

I realized that inside C:\Emgu\emgucv-windesktop3.3.0.2824\libs\ , there are two folders: x64 and x86.  All the dll folders are located in C:\Emgu\emgucv-windesktop3.3.0.2824\bin.
So I added references.
However, I am still getting the same error. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and can not find the solution.

As as workaround I used the [Nuget to install EmguCV 3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EmguCV) and it is very simple to install the environment without issues. 
In the Package Manager (PM) window:

```
PM> Install-Package EmguCV -Version 3.1.0.1
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18940382)

Comment: Another formal workaround is : (1) copy the sample project (e.g. FaceDetection) to another folder. (2) you open the project file.  (3) Delete the Emgu.CV.* in References. (4)Add Emgu.CV.* in References. // Above steps are shown in the youtube [link] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhCRDXAb078 [/link]